# How do I disable off-domain cookies in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, privacy, cookies

In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/62123/187647) on [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), it mentioned:

> Hopefully you already have off-domain cookies turned off, but if not then do that.

Unless I'm mistaken, the concept of an off-domain cookie is this: when I visit example.com, cookies may be stored from example.com and ads.otherserver.com, assuming example.com uses that site for some purposes.

I already use Firefox with private browsing permanently enabled, noscript, and ghostery, among others (although the latter isn't set to disable all cookies). Are off-domain cookies already disabled? If not, how can I disable these off-domain cookies?

EDIT: Just to clarify, my Firefox privacy settings are currently set to this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if any of the mentioned add-ons automatically disable third-party cookies, but you can easily control this within Firefox directly.

The setting is a little bit hidden with *Options* - *Privacy*, just switch to *Use custom settings for history* and you will see the option.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I already use Firefox with private browsing permanently enabled, i.e. my Firefox profile is currently set to "Never remember history." Does this provide the functionality I'm looking for already? (See my edit for exactly how my settings are configured).

Comment: I would say yes, but can proof this anyhow. It makes sense that it is activated automatically by the *Never remember history*, but to be sure, activate *Use custom settings* and deactivate everything.